# Entity framework connection timeout performance issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

Please forgive any obvious errors/misunderstandings! I'm new!

I'm creating a simple c# Winforms app connecting to a sql azure database using entity framework 6, code first.  Dev platform is VS2015 community edition.

A form loads a combobox with record IDs/Names for selection.

Upon record selection via combobox I:

1) Create a new context (disposing prior context first)

2) Load the data graph

3) Populate form

4) Allow user changes

5) (upon user command) Save changes / Dispose of context

My issue is that if I use the combobox to select records the query to populate the data runs in about 30-40ms (according to debug info).  This works while I am busy selecting records.

**However**, If I leave the form unattended for say, 30 seconds and then select a record, the exact same query takes in the region of 500ms.  Same data, connection string, everything.  There must be a connection issue I'm not aware of.  Half a second is not a huge time but it's noticeable and I feel I should understand why.

I pushed up the connection and command timeout properties to large values but same result.

My Azure database is S1 tier.

My connection string is
"Server=tcp:*****.windows.net,1433;Database=*****;User ID=*********;Password=******;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=1200;multipleactiveresultsets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

I am using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy.

My client computer is an i7 4Ghz/16GB Ram/SSD running windows 10 pro.

I would really appreciate some help please.  Thanks.

```
Code sample:
private void LoadRecord(int intID)
{
ResetContext();
var graph = _Context.CareCoordinators
.Where(c => c.CareCoordinatorId.Equals(intID))
.Include("DefaultAreas")
.Include("Branch")
.ToList();
_Subject = graph[0];
}
```

Comment: what code are you using?

Comment: Sorry which bit of code do you need?  The query is         private void LoadRecord(int intID)
        {
            ResetContext();
            var graph = _Context.CareCoordinators
                .Where(c => c.CareCoordinatorId.Equals(intID))
                .Include("DefaultAreas")
                .Include("Branch")
                .ToList();
            _Subject = graph[0];
        }

Comment: Many reasons are possible. Does the connection close after 30 seconds? How many memory does the database engine reserve? Etc.

Comment: @TonyLodge edit code samples into the questions as code blocks, not into the comments.

Comment: @TonyLodge what does `ResetContext()` do?

Comment: Thanks Patrick for your response, I'm not sure how to monitor this I will find out and get back to you if I can figure it out.  Very newbie!  Sorry! :)

Comment: Resetcontext just calls .dispose on the form context and creates a new one.

Comment: i think that could be your problem then. dispose the context after you no longer need it, not before you create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Dispose your context after you have used it, not before you create a new one. That could be what is taking up your time.

Something like the below should help:

```
private void LoadRecord(int intID)
{
    using (Context context = new Context())
    {
        var graph = context.CareCoordinators
        .Where(c => c.CareCoordinatorId.Equals(intID))
        .Include("DefaultAreas")
        .Include("Branch")
        .ToList();
        _Subject = graph[0];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't be more specific as you didn't provide code for the `ResetContext()` method.

Comment: If the context is disposed in this way how can it track and save the changes made by the user?  (Sorry if there's a fundamental loss in my understanding).  Also if you call this method x times with no interval the execution time is 40ms but only when there is a delay between method calls does the 500ms execution time manifest.  Thanks for your time by the way! :)

Comment: Remark: Use the local context reference instead of _Context within the using block.

Comment: @Patrick thanks for pointing that to me - overlooked it earlier.

Comment: @TonyLodge - I've noticed that the longer contexts are kept around, the slower they get over time, particularly for inserts, updates and deletes.

Comment: Seems I may have to go back to the books but just quickly wouldn't _Subject then be disconnected?  How would it be saved? Create a new context and reattach? Thanks

Comment: That's true if entity objects remain on the context. For that reason I always prefer the above pattern, especially in server applications. But this doesn't explain why the query execution time increases up to 500 ms after the application was unattended for 30 seconds.

Comment: @TonyLodge - Yes, that's possible.

Comment: Just another hint: Load the first graph with .FirstOrDefault() instead of .ToList() / index[0] (which may throw an exception when the list is empty by the way). Depending on the number of rows which are loaded from the database and attached as entity objects onto the context, the performance may also be affected.

Comment: @TonyLodge - when you need to check records over time (based on user input), better to create new contexts and then dispose after use.

Comment: Thanks Patrick.  I'm going to mark this as useful (as I am going to have a design rethink with the nice info given) but not answered  (as my inner nerd is telling me I need to understand the variable query timing.  It must be something to do with (IMO) how EF handles open connections to the database or in how Azure handles them (maybe it closes them to maintain its performance as PaaS).  Thanks again for your help guys!

Comment: @TonyLodge - I agree that it's worth to have a look at the connection and the database itself. In my understanding it's not uncommon that the database executes recurrent queries faster as long as it keeps the involved tables and query execution plan cached in memory.